# SQL Graph DB Tables not supporting OLE DB Fast Load?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2019, graph

I try to use SSIS to load in SQL Server Graph DB an edge table, based on the documentation from MSFT it should behave like any normal table, if I use the OLE DB Destination with regular table load it works (but is super slow), so i wanted to use “table or view - fast load” configuration looks as expected but upon execution i get this error.

***An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "JSON data for INSERT/UPDATE of graph pseudocolumn '$edge_id' is malformed.”.***

based on my understanding the edge_id should be auto created, therefore I’m a bit surprised, is fast load not supported on graph tables, hence the documentation is incorrect or what did I miss here ?

Comment: I presume unchecking/checking the triggers/check constraints options has no bearing on the matter?

Comment: unfortunately not :(